# How to position svg circles on a line and curve it?

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js, svg, logic

I am making a software like seats.io and I'm trying to curve the line of the circles. I start by creating a square with svg circles, using d3.js.

The y coordinates

I've started by finding the middle circle and setting it's cy to 0 and the subsequent ones in sequence (incrementing 12 each row. Then I realized that if it was an even number it couldn't find the middle point.

I've decided to use bhaskara formula to find the curve coordinates but I'm stuck on how to position it inside the loop:

```
$("#curve").on("change",function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    var q = quant_col2;

    console.log(q);
    console.log(quant_line2);

    var half = Math.round(quant_col2/2) - 1;

    console.log("media: " + half);

    var value = 0;

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").attr("cy", function(d, i){

        var cy = $(this).attr("cy");

        var resultado = baskara(quant_col2,quant_line2,0);

        var xv = -Math.abs(quant_line2)/(2 * quant_col2);

        var xy = -Math.abs(delta(quant_col2,quant_line2,0))/4 * quant_col2;


        if(i < q){
            if(i  == half) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        if(i == q - 1){
            half = half + quant_col2;
            q = q + quant_col2;
            value = value + 12;
            return cy;
        }

        return cy;
    });

    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

How can it be done to make it curve and the circles be positioned correctly?
I appreciate your help.

edit 1:
Code without data parameter

```
var curva = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d,i) { 
            var cx = $(this).attr("cx");
            return p_parab.x(cx);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d,i) { 
            var cy = $(this).attr("cy");    
            return p_parab.y(cy) + 15* cy;
        });
```

Comment: I've read your question 3 times and have no idea what you are asking.  Can you create some runnable code that illustrates your trouble?

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks! I've created a Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/jaquedeveloper/zvb4uL91/  Click on Draw and Rows and you'll be able to see how it is working now and the formulas

Comment: @Mark, I've been using the solution you've provided and I have a question about it. Do you know how can I have a symmetric result. I need the first and the last circle to be on the same level (y axis). The solution provided on your comment is the best so far and I deeply appreciate your help. This is the final thing I need to do. I've been working on it but still couldn't get this symmetry. This is the only thing left.

Comment: Hi @Mark, I'd like to understand the equation, I could adjust it to run perfectly with 30 circles line. But if the number of circles is less than it, for instance, 10, it doesn't works right. I've made some adjustments on the numbers but I want to automate it in order for it to work no matter how many circles are on each line... how can I make it? Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jaquedeveloper/fpzqf2xr/ To adjust the number of circles, change the quant_col2 variable.

Comment: @steve-ladavich could you help me with this?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are the circles a fixed radius - meaning less circles means a short line?  Are are the circles not a fixed radius - the line is always the same size and the circles grow?  Or are the circles a fixed size and they are spaced evenly on the line?

Comment: Circles have the same size so the distance between them should grow as the parable angle changes

Comment: Then the "line" is always the same length?  That's not what your fiddle shows...

Comment: See this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0C0ntvbOTS0viJSNQmkr?p=preview), adjust numCircles for the amount of circles you want.

Comment: Yes, but the distance between them are fixed. The circles have a 7px radius and a 2px distance between them at the moment they're created. Check the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jaquedeveloper/fpzqf2xr/14/). The only one working as expected is the Row Count = 30 example. You can change the angle range from -3 to the 15. I've "mapped" it by hand. I'd like to automate it but I have no clue about how it can be done. The row count is variable.

Answer (score 2):

I am definitely not sure if I understand your question, but if you are trying to position circles along a curve, I would suggest...

1. write the equation for the curve you want
2. convert that curve to a [parametric equation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Parametric_equation#/Examples_in_two_dimensions)
3. use the x equation for cx, use y equation for cy

The parametric equation will get you a single row. For each additional row you'll want to factor in an additional offset for all cy's in that row.

Here is a very rough example for you to build off of...

```js
const p_circle = {
  x(t){ return 100*Math.cos((t+10)/10)+150 },
  y(t){ return 100*Math.sin((t+10)/10)-80 }
}

const p_parab = {
  x(t){ return -(10*t-5)+100 },
  y(t){ return -(t-5)*(t-5)+20 }
}



let t = Array.prototype.concat(
  Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map(d=>[d,1]), //row 1
  Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map(d=>[d,2]), //row 2
  Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map(d=>[d,3])  //row 3
)


const p_parab_2 = {
  x(t){ return (10*t-5)+100 }, // removing "-" so that first seat is on left, not right
  y(t){ return -(t-5)*(t-5)+20 }
}

// adding 11th seat to center around seat 5 (seat in the center)
let t2 = Array.prototype.concat(
  Array.from(Array(11).keys()).map(d=>[d,1]), //row 1
  Array.from(Array(11).keys()).map(d=>[d,2]), //row 2
  Array.from(Array(11).keys()).map(d=>[d,3])  //row 3
)

console.log(t)

d3.select("svg").selectAll(".circ")
  .data(t)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circ")
    .attr("r",5)
    .attr("fill","red")
    .attr("cx", (d) => p_circle.x(d[0]))
    .attr("cy", (d) => p_circle.y(d[0]) + 15*d[1])

d3.select("svg").selectAll(".parab2")
  .data(t2)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "parab2")
    .attr("r",7)
    .attr("fill","blue")
    .attr("cx", (d) => p_parab.x(d[0]))
    .attr("cy", (d) => p_parab.y(d[0]) + 15*d[1])

d3.select("svg").selectAll(".parab")
  .data(t)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "parab")
    .attr("r",5)
    .attr("fill","green")
    .attr("cx", (d) => p_parab.x(d[0]))
    .attr("cy", (d) => p_parab.y(d[0]) + 15*d[1])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg height="250" width="250"></svg>
```

Comment: Yes, you've understood the question, that's what I need! But I see this curves are pending to left and I'd like the y coordinates of the left-most and right-most elements be the same... how can I achieve it? Does this has some relation with the cos and sin values?

Comment: Play around with the parametric equations and the "t" values until you get it to look how you want it. Remember that the equations are plotting curves and the t values say where along the curve you want to plot each circle. For this curve t=5 is the center seat, but I have seats t=0 to t=10 (11 seats). Because of the way I wrote the eq. the 0th seat is 1 seat futher from center than seat 10 and gives the impression it's "pending left" -- I'll add an edit

Comment: I just adjusted the width and changed a parameter of the curve and it worked. I don't have the d data for the number... I tried to put only the cy and cx values in my automation code and it didn't worked as expected. How can I adjust it? I've edited the question

Comment: @JaquelinePassos, the ".data()" part is sort of hiding a for loop/ array.prototype.map call inside D3. With ".data().enter().append()" there you draw a new circle for each seat. You'll probably want to create data based on some function like makeSeatArray(nRows = 5, nCols = 10){ return a 2d array } and then render accordingly with the general update pattern https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234

Comment: @JaquelinePassos in the JS fiddle you linked you use double for loop on lines 111, 112 -- the D3 data binding basically handles that for you. I would HIGHLY recommend you leverage D3 for it's data binding, but if you want to do it manually, you'll have to incorporate those for loops back into this approach (and draw each circle "manually")

Answer (score 2):

I like @steveladavich's answer but I'll propose an alternate.  You can use `d3`'s ability to curve fit to points and then place the circles on the resulting path:

```js
var r = 10,
  points = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  points.push({
    x: (500 / 10) * i,
    y: Math.random() * 500
  });
}

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);

var path = svg.append("g")
  .datum(points)
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", line)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "none")
  .node();

var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(d3.range(0, pathLength, r))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var p = path.getPointAtLength(d);
    return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
  })
  .attr("r", r / 2)
  .style("fill", "steelblue");
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mark and @JaquelinePassos, I think this is the better answer. Letting D3/SVG do the work of creating the curve is easier than managing it yourself via x/y equations. The addition of `getPointAtLength()` is also an improvement on creating an array of t values. 

For this application, I think using this approach with a d3 path generator like `quadraticCurveTo()` (rather than d3's curve fit) would make this answer even better. At that point, modifying control points would make for an easily editable/customizable solution

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about how to make it work using this, because I don't have a real line. The circles are disposed as if they're on the same line, and I have a number x of lines. I couldn't get the wanted result with this method... The closer result I've got from the wanted result is this: https://jsfiddle.net/jaquedeveloper/gcg2m3s2/ . Still I'm looking for how I can make it in different levels. For instance, a similar x and y value (to get a "almost straight" line... and then making it distance from one another... any help is appreciated

Comment: @JaquelinePassos, still not completely sure what you are going for but see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pNXV3Qj6wYPaIQRzzTO0?p=preview) for one possible implementation.  Adjust `parabDepth` for a larger curve.

Comment: @Mark it works as seat rows, like a cinema map, where I have svg circles representing the seats, side by side in one "line". I don't have a real line, when I say line it means the circles have the same y values... each line is one row. I want to specify the curve, the user will be able to set the curve specification to create a representation of the seats. The answer you provided works well for it so far! Thank you very much! I'll implement it and probably accept it.